# matplotlib text (and figtext) error

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm trying to plot text values instead of symbols (for an MDS solution), and `matplotlib.pyplot` is giving me errors I don't understand. I've updated ipython and matplotlib to make sure it's not an old problem (or a problem with old versions), and I haven't been able to find any answers or reports of similar problems here (or elsewhere via google).

So, for example, after invoking `ipython --pylab`, if I type:

```
x = random.rand(4)
y = random.rand(4)
s = [str(i) for i in arange(4)+1]

text(x,y,s)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in
    draw_wrapper draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in 
    draw_wrapper draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in 
    draw_wrapper draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 547, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 287, in 
    _get_layout key = self.get_prop_tup()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 696, in 
    get_prop_tup x, y = self.get_position()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 684, in   
    get_position x = float(self.convert_xunits(self._x))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I get the same error if I try calling text with scalars rather than vectors/lists (e.g., `text(x[0],y[0],s[0])`, or any number of variants of the arguments to the `text` function). The same thing happens:

- with `figtext`,
- if I manually `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and call `plt.text`, and
- if I explicitly make figure and subplot objects and/or call `scatter(x,y)` first.

Also, for what it's worth, once this problem occurs, the error message appears again if I manually resize the figure. Possibly related is the fact that changes to figures don't update automatically, but only after I plot in another subplot or manually resize the figure. But I digress.

I've got an updated installation of Anaconda on a Mac (with Mavericks), and, as mentioned above, I'm using iPython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.text` expects a single x, y, and string values, not sequences. (See: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text )

Just use a loop.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.rand(2,4)
s = [str(i) for i in np.arange(1, 5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
text = [ax.text(*item) for item in zip(x, y, s)]
plt.show()
```

[image]